# An extension $w$ of a valuation $v$ induced from $\mathfrak{p}$ come from ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ above $\mathfrak{p}$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Assume the standard context for extension of valuations.

An extension $w$ of a valuation $v$ induced from a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ comes from a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ above $\mathfrak{p}$?

Is tris true? I strongly believe so, but I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: Your question is unclear, are you working with number fields or something more general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume we're working with number fields.  Let $L$ be a finite extension of $K$, and $w$ an absolute value on $L$ which, when restricted to $K$, is equivalent to an absolute value $||_P$ obtained from some prime $P$ of $K$.  Let $A, B$ be the rings of integers of $K, L$.  We want to find a prime $Q$ of $L$ which lies over $K$ which induces an absolute value equivalent to $w$.

Let $O = \{ x \in L : |x|_w = |x| \leq 1\}$ have unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak M = \{ x \in L : |x| < 1 \}$.  We want to find a prime $Q$ of $L$ for which $O = B_Q$ and $\mathfrak M = Q B_Q$ (then we're pretty much done).  Now $$O \cap K = \{ x \in K : |x| = |x|_P \leq 1 \} = A_P$$ $$ \mathfrak M \cap K = \{ x \in K : |x|_P < 1 \} = PA_P$$ Now the elements of $B$, which are integral over $A$, can also be seen to have absolute value $\leq 1$.  Therefore $B \subseteq O$.  We let $Q = \mathfrak M \cap B$.  It follows that $Q$ lies over $P$, since $Q \cap A = PA_P \cap A = P$.  Now you want to argue that $$O = B_Q$$ and $$\mathfrak M = QB_Q$$ but this isn't too hard.  Let me know if you run into any difficulties.